# Print data from a C# ToList

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

My Code for making the list is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
List<it_position> GetAllPositions(){
   PositionDataClassesDataContext context = new PositionDataClassesDataContext();
   var result = from positions in context.it_positions select positions;
  return result.ToList();
}
```

And I get the data from a method

```
PositionServiceReference.PositionServiceClient service = new   
     PositionServiceReference.PositionServiceClient();
service.GetAllPositionsCompleted += new   
EventHandler<PositionServiceReference.GetAllPositionsCompletedEventArgs>
          (service_GetAllPositionsCompleted);
service.GetAllPositionsAsync();
```

But how can I get the result to be arrays that I can use? They are now just ItemSoruces in datalist...

```
void service_GetAllPositionsCompleted(object sender, 
            PositionServiceReference.GetAllPositionsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dgEmployee.ItemsSource = e.Result;

}
```

Comment: What is the type of ```PositionServiceReference.GetAllPositionsCompletedEventArgs.Result```?

Comment: I have a rather different question....what is it that you need to do with an array that you cannot do with a List?  List supports indexing and random access, enumeration, ItemAt, InsertAt, RemoveAt...etc etc. and so on.  Not sure why you would even need to cast it to an array in the first place....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint at this line:

`dgEmployee.ItemsSource = e.Result;`

and hoover the mouse over `e.Result`, you will see that it is infact a `IEnumrable<it_position>`
If you need to use it before/after setting `e.Result` simply cast it - like this:

```
void service_GetAllPositionsCompleted(object sender, 
            PositionServiceReference.GetAllPositionsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //var lst = e.Result as IEnumerable<it_positions>; <-- This gave error
    var lst = e.Result; // <-- This worked fine
    var ary = lst.ToArray();
    //go do fun stuff with the array
    dgEmployee.ItemsSource = e.Result;

}
```

Comment: Ok - instead of List, try use IEnumerable<it_positions>

Comment: Thank you. "var lst = e.Result;" Worked for me.